# Eigenvalue and Eigenvector for the linear transformation in $ \mathbb{Z}_2^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to find the Eigenvalue and Eigenvector for the Linear transformation:
$T:\mathbb{Z}_2^4 \to \mathbb{Z}_2^4: (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(x_1+x_3,-2x_1-x_3,x_2+x_4,x_2-x_4)$
My problem is with $\mathbb{Z}_2^4$ cause I've never worked with this before.
So what I did:
I've found the representing matrix  of the transformation using the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and got $$ [T]_B^B= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \end{array} \right)$$
Then did $det([T]_B^B-\lambda I)$ and received $\lambda ^2(\lambda +1)(\lambda -1)$ as characteristic polynomial, so I've said that there are two Eigenvalue: $$\lambda_1=0, \lambda_2=1, \lambda_3=-1 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$$ So for zero I got $$ sp \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \end{array} \right)$$ and for 1 I got $$ sp \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 \end{array} \right)$$
Is this right?

Comment: The zero vector is *never* an eigenvector. 0101 is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue zero. And 0001 is not an eigenvector for the eigenvalue 1, but 1000 is.

Comment: I fixed my eigenvector of 1, didn't quite understand how you got the answer for zero and will thank you if you explain.

Comment: The 2nd & 4th columns are equal, so 0101 is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue zero.